# How to move VIM's status-line and command-line to the top of the window?

Tags: vim, macvim

I don't like them at the bottom of the display. Instead, I want them located at the top.

I didn't find any command to config it that way. Are there any?

Or are there any switches in the source files I can config to build one customized version?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is not going to be possible without hacking the source, and I suspect it will be fairly non-trivial to do; Vim's use of the status area when showing command output is not simple.

Comment: it is "fairly non-trivial" to decipher that trio =P

Comment: @puk: Sorry, but I can't make sense of your comment.  What "trio"?

Comment: "Fairly non trivial". It's not quite an oxymoron, but still a little confusing.